# React JS: Rendering object keys and its values

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I am trying to render an objects key and value, however it just doesn't seem to work.

I have managed to display it in the console, but not the actual dom.
I am iterating through the object which has multiple entries.

What do I need to do to actually print out the values?

```
{attributes.map(items => {                                
                            {Object.keys(items).map((key) => {
                                console.log(key, items[key]);
                            })}
                        })}
```

Answer (score 9):

Like this:

```
{attributes.map((items, index) => {
  return (
    <ul key={index}>
    {Object.keys(items).map((key) => {
      return (
        <li key={key + index}>{key}:{items[key]}</li>
      )
    })}
    </ul>
  )
})}
```